# In Android studio, how to get symbol window for the current java file?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, android-studio-2.3

In `Android studio` 2.3.3 , how to get symbol window for the current java file ?

Symbol window means, which generally present in a IDE as left panel or right panel and list the functions and imports on the current java file. Similar to `Symbol Window` in `Source Insight`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the `Structure` window. `Alt-7` or `View->Tool Windows->Structure`